# Query to split using Regexp data split not getting correct result oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr, regexp-like

I am trying to classify the tables into various categories ,but i was not able to get the desired result , please check the below query results , existing results along with the expected results

STANDARD

NON_STANDARD

TEMPORARY

TO_BE_DROPPED

```
SELECT OWNER,        
       OBJECT_NAME,          
       REGEXP_REPLACE(OBJECT_NAME, '^([A-Z0-9$]{1,})_([A-Z0-9$]{1,})_.*','\1_\2')AS  BEGINNING,          
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(OBJECT_NAME, '[^_]*$') AS ENDING,       
  CASE       
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^D(S[CP]?|T)_.+_(T|(W0?[123]?))$')        
   THEN          
     'STANDARD'          
     WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^DB_.+_(D|F|T|W|W1|W2|W3)$')         
       THEN  
     'STANDARD'          
     WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^DE_.+_(D|F|L|T|W|W01|W02|W03|W1|W2|W3)$')       
  THEN       
     'STANDARD'      
     WHEN OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'TBD%'        
    THEN  
        'TO_BE_DROPPED'  
     WHEN OBJECT_NAME LIKE 'TMP%'        
     THEN 'TEMPORARY_TABLE'      
     WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^DA_.+_(D|F|L|T|W|W01|W02|W03|W1|W2|W3|A|AD|AM|AQ|AY)$')         
   THEN          
     'STANDARD'          
     ELSE 'NON_STANDARD'         
   END       
   AS TABLE_CLASSIFICATION        
FROM   DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE  OWNER IN ('DI_ABC')  
       AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
GROUP  BY OWNER,         
          OBJECT_NAME        
ORDER  BY OWNER DESC,
          OBJECT_NAME;
```

**EXISTING RESULTS**

```
SNO OWNER  OBJECT_NAME        BEGINNING ENDING  TABLE_CLASSIFICATION 
01  DI_SCC DSC_02_CUST_ORD    DSC_02    ORD      NON_STANDARD
02  DI_SCC DSC_02_CUST_ORD_T  DSC_02    T        NON_STANDARD
03  DI_SCC DSC_02_CUST_ORD_W  DSC_02    W        NON_STANDARD
04  DI_SCC DSC_02_CUST_ORD1   DSC_02    ORD1     NON_STANDARD
05  DI_SCC DSC_02_CUST_ORD_4  DSC_02    4        NON_STANDARD
06  DI_SCC DSP_03_CUST_SHP    DSP_03    SHP      NON_STANDARD
07  DI_SCC DSP_03_CUST_SHP_T  DSP_03    T        NON_STANDARD
08  DI_SCC DSP_03_CUST_SHP_W  DSP_03    W        NON_STANDARD
09  DI_SCC DSP_03_CUST_SHP9   DSP_03    SHP9     NON_STANDARD
10  DI_SCC DSP_03_CUST_SHP_62 DSP_03    62       NON_STANDARD
14  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD        DT        WRD      NON_STANDARD
15  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD_T      DT        T        NON_STANDARD
16  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD_W      DT        W        NON_STANDARD
17  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD5       DT        WRD5     NON_STANDARD
18  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD_8      DT        8        NON_STANDARD
19  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD23      DT        WRD23    NON_STANDARD
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
SNO OWNER  OBJECT_NAME        BEGINNING ENDING  TABLE_CLASSIFICATION 
01  DI_SCC DSC_02_CUST_ORD    DSC_02    ORD      STANDARD
02  DI_SCC DSC_02_CUST_ORD_T  DSC_02    T        STANDARD
03  DI_SCC DSC_02_CUST_ORD_W  DSC_02    W        STANDARD
04  DI_SCC DSC_02_CUST_ORD1   DSC_02    ORD1     NON_STANDARD
05  DI_SCC DSC_02_CUST_ORD_4  DSC_02    4        NON_STANDARD
06  DI_SCC DSP_03_CUST_SHP    DSP_03    SHP      STANDARD
07  DI_SCC DSP_03_CUST_SHP_T  DSP_03    T        STANDARD
08  DI_SCC DSP_03_CUST_SHP_W  DSP_03    W        STANDARD
09  DI_SCC DSP_03_CUST_SHP9   DSP_03    SHP9     NON_STANDARD
10  DI_SCC DSP_03_CUST_SHP_62 DSP_03    62       NON_STANDARD
14  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD        DT        WRD      STANDARD
15  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD_T      DT        T        STANDARD
16  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD_W      DT        W        STANDARD
17  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD5       DT        WRD5     NON_STANDARD
18  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD_8      DT        8        NON_STANDARD
19  DI_SCC DT_CUST_WRD23      DT        WRD23    NON_STANDARD
```

i am trying to correct it in order to get the EXPECTED results , what i need to correct it ?

```
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^D(S[CP]?|T)_.+_([A-Z$])$')
```

any suggestions what must be modified in the above reg ex statement ?

```
--this case statement is for schema - DI_STAGE
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^D(S[CP]?|T)_.+_(T|(W0?[123]?))$')
--this case statement is for schema - DI_ODS
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^DB_.+_(D|F|T|W|W1|W2|W3)$')
--this case statement is for schema - DI_EDW
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^DE_.+_(D|F|L|T|W|W01|W02|W03|W1|W2|W3)$')   
--this case statement is for schema - DI_MART
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^DE_.+_(D|F|L|T|W|W01|W02|W03|W1|W2|W3)$')
'^DA_.+_(D|F|L|T|W|W01|W02|W03|W1|W2|W3|A|AD|AM|AQ|AY)$')
```

Comment: Please post the data for your test case in DDL(create table) and DML(insert) statements for us to help you better. Also, remember to post the database version. Lastly, explain the rules supporting your desired output.

Comment: 1). you regular expressions in the query (`'^W(S[CP]?|T)_.+_([A-Z$])$'`) and in the question at the end (`'^D(S[CP]?|T)_.+_([A-Z$])$'`) don't match.  2). you don't actually expain what logic you *want* the regular expression to check.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - This is DBA_OBJECTS table which is common table so the structure remains same , Oracle DB - Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

Comment: @MatBailie - basically if the table ending is number then it must be classified as NON_STANDARD

Comment: @rakesh 1. Even if it's metadata table, it's not necessary the structure remains same as it depends on Oracle version. 2. We don't have your data so you must adhere to the posting rules. 3. **Explain the rules supporting your desired output.** Otherwise, you might get half answers which wouldn't help you anyway.

Comment: not sure but check [here][https://regex101.com/r/PBhNWz/1] to isolate issues...

Answer (score 1):

If you really only need to check if the string ends with a numeric value *(as per your comment)*...

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=66a0e1d6180f3eb1c3b80c06763e8654

```
CASE WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECTNAME, '[0-9]+$') THEN 'STANDARD' ELSE 'OTHER' END
```

***EDIT:***

Your comment below ***implies*** that if the table name doesn't start with `DSC_`, `DSP_` or `DT_`, then the result should be `NONSTANDARD`.  The simplest way to check for the presence of that would be `(DSC|DSP|DT)\_`

This gives me...

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECTNAME, '^(DSP|DSC|DT)\_(.)*[A-Z]$') THEN 'STANDARD' ELSE 'OTHER' END
```

To be `STANDARD`, all of the following must be true

- Must start with `DSC_`, `DSP_` or `DT_`
- Must end with a capital letter

Until your question is clarified with a more complete and exact set of requirements, this is only my best *guess* as to what you're trying to achieve.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=56bdf881655ec8cd3292931303b86ea1

***EDIT:***

The main difference between where I ended up, and you example, is that you have `$` in there twice...

- `([A-Z$])$`

Thus, requiring two "end of line".

Change that to `[A-Z]$` And it's much the same as I have.

Comment: the reason choosing WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(OBJECT_NAME, '^D(S[CP]?|T)_.+_([A-Z$])$')   this is since there are there tables groups (DS,DSC,DT) so this is must '^D(S[CP]?|T)_

Comment: @rakesh - Then your comment is incomplete.  Please update your question with ***the exact and Complete set of rules*** that you wish your regular expression to check.

Comment: in some case where ever the table is having TEMP/TMP it is not considering the case statement it is classifying it as STANDARD but the expected result is 'TEMPORARY'